# Capturing out of order, optional, groups with regular expression using fluentd

Tags: regex, fluentd

I am parsing a log file that have several, known, groups in any part of the message. All the possible groups are known (there are around 7).

Messages have the following form:

```
This is the message from [username:john] and he is [age:34] years old
Another message from a [age:87] years old user known as [username:paul]
Yet another message of [username:erick] with a [score:12] and no age.
```

I tried to parse it using a parse like:

```
  <parse>
    @type regexp
    expression /\[username:(?<username>.*?)\]|\[age:(?<age>.*?)\]|\[score:(?<score>.*?)\]/g
  </parse>
```

But it only captures one group. I need to capture all of them.

Is it possible to do what I am trying without creating several filters, each with a different part of the expression.

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/c4IVdV/1

Comment: @PM77-1 you ar using global modifier. In fluentd that modifier doesnt work